# c# mvc get url parameter within an attribute

Tags: c#, url, parameters, attributes

In my controller I have this "SomeAttribute" which validates an url. It checks whether the provided ID in the url is a valid ID and whether the category name is the relevant category name of the given ID.

```
[SomeAttribute]
public ActionResult SomeAction() 
{
    ....
}
```

However, in my attribute I don't know how can I reach the current url parameters.

```
public SomeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
      string myurl = HttpContext.Current.Request["mystring"] // this does not work
   }
}
```

So basically my question is, how can I reach the url of the current context within an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Well in case you need url parameters within an attribute and you are using routing, this is the solution:

```
filterContext.RouteData.Values["mystring"]
```